# MySQL server connections capped at 1013

Tags: mysql

For the last few days I've been trying to figure out why my MySQL read slave servers are capped at 1012+1 (+1 for the superuser) connections when I have the max_connections set to 5000. It seems that no matter what I change, the "Historic max_used_connections" never increases beyond 1013.

The mysql read slaves support a high traffic web site. I have a cluster of 3 read only slaves. Each read slave seems to be capped at 1013 max connections. I can take two out of the cluster so all connections go to one and still only 1013. **No error messages show up in the mysql log file.**

A **mysqladmin status** on one of the read slaves shows this:
Uptime: 1661  Threads: 128  Questions: 17634224  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 2441  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 938  Queries per second avg: 10616.630

Same server, **mtop** shows this:
load average: 0.05, 0.15, 0.19 mysqld 5.1.66-log up 0 day(s),  0:28 hrs
106 threads: 4 running, 906 cached. Queries/slow: 1.6K/0 Cache Hit: 99.96% 
Opened tables: 0  RRN: 278  TLW: 1.0K  SFJ: 0  SMP: 0  QPS: 1

Each server has 12 dual-core Intel CPU's (24 cores) with 140 GB of RAM running RHEL 6.3, Kernel 2.6. (x86_64)

Any idea what would be limiting/capping the connections at 1012+1 ?

**EDIT**
Also wanted to add two things:

1) I am running the "free/community" edition of MySQL that you get from a Red Hat 6.3 YUM install. Could there be some limitation in that version?

2) I've changed the /etc/security/limits.conf file on the MySQL read slaves, increasing values for users mysql and root (did not help my situation):

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1161534
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32768
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: client-side (e.g. php, apache maxchilds) limits lower than the server limits?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but could it be the file descriptor limit?

Comment: 1013 sounds suspiciously close to the default 1024 file handle limit imposed on most operating systems.

Comment: @MarcB no, according to our Apache configuration we could potentially have a total (all Apache servers that connect to the db's) of 8400 connections.

Comment: @Patrickdev do you mean the "open_files_limit" in MySQL? If so I have that currently set to 65535.

Comment: @tadman thats the direction I was looking at, however any change in Linux (ulimit, etc) that I've set seems to make no difference.

Comment: Remember `ulimit` only applies to that shell and doesn't affect other processes.

Comment: @tadman I made sure I changed it for the user mysql, but as you mentioned I don't think it applies to the mysql service processes. but I could be mistaken.

Comment: You may have to hack a `ulimit` call into the `mysqld_safe` script or whatever it is that launches your `mysqld` process. I've had to do this in the past to ensure that it's properly opened up.

Comment: What is MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS set to? It defines a per-user connection limit.

Comment: @Phil all user accounts have unlimited connections (set to 0)

Comment: This is the equivalent of "is it plugged in?" but how did you set the max connections to 5000? Is it set globally? In my.cnf before restart? Other?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue.  Put this at the top of the mysql start script.

ulimit -u 102400 -n 102400

Has to be at mysql start time.

Comment: An updated answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977095/how-to-set-max-connections-in-mysql-permanently/41991231#41991231